# QGIS: Expression WHEN property1 = 'FOO' THEN property2 = 'BAR'

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

Our Foundation is adding additional properties to points.

If property1 = FOO , then add property2 = BAR

```
    WHEN
        property1 = 'FOO' THEN property2 = 'BAR'
    END
```

When I run this the property1 column is deleted. Can you help me with the syntax, here, please?

Assumptions/Knowns:
This is a spatialite layer. property1 and property2 columns both exist. I am using QGIS 2.4. I opened the attributes tables to use the Expression dialog. The property1 column is selected when the expression is executed. property1 and property2 are columns, and I am aware that " is sometimes used to enclose columns. I do need to store these values for use in other programs where they cannot be so easily derived from the data.

I saw several examples that changed the current value of property1: `WHEN property1 = A THEN 1` but this only changes the value in the query column, and I am looking to insert another value property2 based on the value of property1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked and selected the correct target field = "property2" for "update selected field"?

[image]

no need to set update field in syntax.

try the below syntax.

```
CASE
   WHEN  "property1" = 'FOO' THEN 'BAR'
END
```